# DFT derivative property?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

Does it have one? The continuous variant does, $f'(t) \rightarrow j \omega F(\omega)$ - but $jkX[k]$ definitely isn't it for DFT.

To find it there must be a useful simplification of $\text{DFT}(x[n] - x[n-1])$, where $x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{j2\pi kn/N}$, while also accounting for the one dropped sample (`x[0]`) - and I cannot see such a simplification.

---

**Note**: $x[n] = ...$ above is for the definition of IDFT I use, rather than where the signal derives from. The signal should be assumed the most general possible; not periodic, can be complex or real, but must be finite.

**Note2**: see my answer for some important caveats to (and direct contradicting of) the accepted answer, and optionally the comments discussions below answers. Thanks to @CedronDawg for the detailed discussion.

**Note3**: "derivative" = finite difference (for sake of this question).

**Edit 2023**: hijacking the question for visibility, the exact question effectively asks for `fft(x[1:]) - fft(x[:-1])`; this requires "DFT trim property". We [have that](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81994/50076) for `x[:len(x)//2]`, and it can perhaps extend to `x[:-1]` via fractional resampling. Olli's answer works great for$^{1}$ `fft(x[:-1]) ~= fft(x)` (which has many use cases). For "derivative" as in differentiating via frequency domain, "trigonometric differentiation" may be of interest, summarized [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86132/50076).

<sup>1: as in predicting `fft(diff(x))` from only `fft(x)`; it's exact for `fft(x[:-1])`</sup>

Comment: strictly speaking, there is no derivative operator applied to discrete sequences.  there are no differential equations involving discrete sequences, but we ***do*** approximate (or emulate) differential equations with **difference equations**.  that said, your *"derivative"* could be meaningfully replaced with a difference but there are issues involved in doing so.  one of the issues is an apparent offset of $\frac12$ sample when the discrete samples are cast back into a continuous function using the reconstruction theorem.

Comment: (continuing from Cedron's 2nd answer's comments) "it shouldn't matter" i.e., whether or not $x[n]$ "comes from $X[k]$" or vice versa, both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ _in the analysis frame_ (from 0 to N-1) are the same. But in case x[-1] is relevant, then yes, $x[n]$ is the original, with samples outside the frame.

Comment: (also con't from my second answer)  Because Olli got it first and got it right.  I took us off on a tangential tour due to my misinterpretation of the question.  I'm pleased that was more educational for you.

Comment: @CedronDawg Not just for me, but for any future reader; our discussion added much value to this entire thread. Alright, I'll note it in my question - after finishing a sort of discussion summary in my answer.

Comment: *// "it shouldn't matter" i.e., whether or not $x[n]$ "comes from $X[k]$" or vice versa, both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ in the analysis frame (from $0$ to $N-1$) are the same.//*  -- not sure what this sentence means, or has anything to do with the fact of inherent periodic extension to the DFT. $$ $$  *//But in case $x[-1]$ is relevant, then yes, $x[n]$ is the original, with samples outside the frame.//* -- my point is that Ced is explicitly making use of "$x[-1]$" and Ced denies the inherent periodic extension of the DFT.  If Ced puts it into his/her equations, that $x[-1]$ must have **some** value.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Neither of us deny the _extension_'s periodicity, no - we simply say it's not required to get the DFT _of the analysis frame_, or to reconstruct _the frame_. We say that the extension cannot describe anything about the _original signal_. As for my sentence; I'm saying the DFT and its inverse will be exactly the same in both scenarios. -- P.S., pardon if I speak wrongly on Cedron's behalf.

Comment: Ced denies the property *inherent* to the DFT that is periodic extension of the data passed to it.  so i suspect you *are* misrepresenting his position.  i will try to be careful to not represent it and will let Ced speak for him/herself.  i have been trying to corner Ced into taking a position regarding the relationship that $x[N-1]$ has to $x[0]$ in the DFT.  (it is clear that it is exactly the same relationship that $x[0]$ has to $x[1]$ and my understanding of Ced's position is that he/she denies this.) any shifting in the DFT, **must** be circular because of inherent periodic extension.

Comment: @CedronDawg It suddenly dawned on me that I might've hastily given up on $x'(n)$, as it was _not_ based on `x[n]-x[n-1]`, which is what I used to check it. It's still true that we can't roll with $(n)$ - but I'm out of arguments if we simply use $[n]$. Your expression handled a linear chirp fairly well in terms of shape, comparing with `np.diff`, and since latter indeed isn't a "true" derivative, it's not obvious which is "more correct". There's math work to be done to justify continuous-differentiating and then discretizing again, but maybe it can be done after all.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Himself.  OLGD has represented my position succinctly and correctly.  I urge your to reread both my answers here, as well as the comments in the other thread.  It is you that have consistently misrepresented what I've said and I'm tired of trying to correct you.  Modular arithmetic does not require "an extension" to perform a rotation.  Snipping the analysis frame out of the signal and wrapping it in a circle is a more accurate portrayal.  I originally understood the meaning of $X[-1]$ to be the original signal, not the extension of the inverse DFT of the spectrum.

Comment: The math was done in my answer.  By allowing n to be real in the definition of of the inverse DFT, the definition of the "trigonometric interpolation function" is achieved.  Clearly $x[n] = x(n)$ on the integers.  It can be differentiated, and the derivative evaluated at each point.  My oops was not selecting the minimum bandwidth interpolation function.  Again $(x[n+1]-x[n-1])/2$ is a better approximation to $x'(n)$.  I was confused by RB-J's first comment as I had already made the same points and he said that he had read my answer.

Comment: The discussion (with RB-J) in the fluffy cloud link arose when he asserted the Nyquist bin "had" to be split on the high and low side.  For a real valued signal it doesn't matter since the imaginary part of the bin is zero and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.  In my code below it is fully on the negative side.  For complex valued signals it is best to split it, but nothing (bandwidth-wise) says you have to.  A lesson you can draw from that is that odd N frame sizes with a zero centered signal frame and a zero centered spectrum is the "most natural" configuration. The same is true in my eigenvector studies.

Comment: *//I'm tired of trying to correct you.//* ---
it's because you're wrong and the mathematics say that you're wrong and your attempt to *"correct"* me doesn't take. ...
*// Modular arithmetic does not require "an extension" to perform a rotation..//* --- Modular arithmetic ***is*** an extension to perform a shift of data that is periodic. So take whatever DFT theorem that implies shifting of the data in either domain, that shifting **must** require modulo-$N$ arithmetic. So if you define simply:

$$ y[n] = x[ n \mod N ] \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

then how periodic is $y[n]$?

Comment: For the last time, you can extend the inverse DFT of the spectrum in the time domain to your heart's content, and the result will be periodic, but that is no reason to assume the originating signal is, or pretend it is.  That's sort of like saying a ROL, ROR, RCL or RCR assembly language instruction makes the register shift into another register so it can rotate.  It's nonsense.  The inverse will match the original signal on the analysis frame, that is all you can say.  The rotation doesn't occur until you take the inverse DFT.  I'm done with you here too.  Let others judge as they may.

Comment: *// but that is no reason to assume the originating signal is,//* -- can you show me anywhere that i mentioned the term *"originating signal"*?  (please don't misrepresent my position.) ....
*// or pretend it is.//* -- no pretending.  when you pass $N$ contiguous samples of $x[n]$ to the DFT (regardless of the origin), the DFT periodically extends the data in all of its math and in any theorem where it makes a difference (pretty much anything other than linearity and scaling), so that $$x[n+N]=x[n] \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ That is simply a mathematical fact.

Comment: now Ced, when are you going to answer my question?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No.  It is clear to me you are the one not following the discussion and any further attempts of clarification are futile.  When the understanding of what we have been talking about hits you, feel free to come back.

Comment: @CedronDawg, i am not accepting your false mathematic axioms.  i am not accepting your self-assessed authority and i am calling you out on promoting false mathematical claims, on being inconsistent with your own mathematical claims and on bad engineering practices regarding units and dimensions.  anyone who says that $2$ or $2 \pi$ or any other dimensionless number has units is simply mistaken and your understanding is pedantic. you should not be propagating this misunderstanding. you claim that the DFT does not inherently periodically extend the data passed to it, yet you make use of $x[-1]$.

Comment: even though you claim to be, you are not really a DFT expert.  you have a pedantic understanding of it and you've made some either false or inconsistent claims.  and you never once answered **any** of the questions or challenges put to you.

Comment: What does dropping `x[0]` mean?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo well, I was already pretty sure, even without reading, that neither of the answers were trying to prove the *unexisting* derivative property of DFT, but then the only real problem to be solved in this question is to find the correct question to ask for what is being answered below... :-)))

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson This is not an argument about how the math works (I hope), but how it should be described.  My second answer repeats your questions and then does a thorough answer.  If that answer is unsatisfactory to you, well I can't control that, but to say I didn't answer is a prevarication.
$$ $$
Starting with:

$$ z[n] = x[ n \mod N ] \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

You can say:

$$ z[n] = z[n+N] $$

You can't say:

$$ x[n] = x[n+N] $$

It might be true, but likely not.  You are saying one should assume it is true, I am denying that.

Comment: Phenomenal fireworks to log on to. I'm inclined agree with Cedron that RBJ is, in fact, not following the discussion closely enough; much of accusations are resolved by comments made outside the immediate context, on this very Q&A. Example: RBJ: "Ced denies X and you misinterpret him" -- Ced: "No, I was interpreted correctly." -- RBJ: "No, you're wrong" ... ?? -- I'll see if I find time to make a guided Q&A on DFT's periodicity 'assumption'.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Finite difference demands dropping a sample; it operates on two points, starting from `x[0]`, ending with `x[N-1]`, which can only produce `N-1` points, unless we impute one somehow. I say drop `x[0]` since that's what Python's `numpy.diff` does.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you wish to have an expression for a length $N-1$ DFT of backward difference of $x$ given a length $N$ DFT of $x$?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Not given a DFT; see Note1, and Ctrl + F "my sentence", that comment and one above it. Pretty sure your and Cedron's answer already did the job, I've just yet to hear Cedron agree that the slope term will always drop.

Comment: If Olli does formulate a proper N point spectrum of a signal to a N-1 point spectrum of the backward finite difference of the signal transform then he should get the check for sure.  When I realized that was the issue, I considered trying, but didn't, hence my hack "reframe the problem" comment in my j;first answer which requires taking the inverse DFT, taking the difference with shortening the frame, then taking the DFT.  It seems to me that a simple formulation is not possible, but I haven't tried.

Comment: My first answer is based on the input signal, not the inverse DFT of the spectrum, but it also works for the latter.  In the latter case the slope term will always drop.

Comment: @CedronDawg No, it *must* drop, always. If not, what do you say to my counterexample? What if x[-1] = 100^100?

Comment: If the finite backward difference is based on the input signal, call it $y[n] =x[n]-x[n-1]$ prior to the selection of the analysis frame then $Y[k]$ cannot be determined from $X[k]$ without considering the value of $x[-1]$.  Dropping the slope term is equivalent to saying $x[-1]=x[N-1]$.  Naturally, a N periodic signal satisfies that and is a much stronger condition than required, so I am not sure what you mean by your counter example.  If you do the "dropped sample approach" and want to find $Y_{N-1}[k]$ from $X_{N}[k]$ then $x[0]$, determinable from $X_{N}[k]$, plays the role of $x[-1]$

Comment: @CedronDawg I have to agree with Robert here. You don't need to introduce new *fancy* math just to show that the DFT implies circular first difference, instead of the linear one. And to get the **effect** of linear first difference, all you have to do is to append one zero to the end of x[n], and use N+1 length DFT. And btw, DFT = DFS. It's nothing new. And it's circular all the way. But the **link** between a linear sequence $x[n]$ and its circular (periodic) extension $\tilde{x}[n]$ should be made very clear at the beginning so as to allow readers correctly interpret what you are doing..

Comment: @Fat32 I've prepended my answer with an explanatory note.  Hopefully that is satisfactory to all.  In the terminology of the discussion I would say "DFS = Extended Inverse DFT", but I have no strong interest in that issue.  I don't think I introduced any "fancy math", I just addressed the problem from the definition rather than applying the circular convolution property of the DFT.  Did you mean "append x[0] to the end"?  This still wouldn't be correct to get the backward finite difference.

Comment: @Fat32 How about this, for an unnormalized DFT?

$$ Y_{linear}[k] = Y_{circular}[k] + ( x[N-1] - x[-1] ) $$

Seeking the linear backward finite difference implies that x[-1] exists.

Comment: @CedronDawg I'm saying let's assume you're right, and consider the implications. The implication is, a sample _outside the frame_ which we're transforming (in this case, taking the "derivative" of), has a "say" on samples _inside the frame_. So we take zeros from `0` to `N-1`, and insert a bomb at `x[-1]`; now the "derivative", which should be zero over the frame, is far from it.

Comment: @CedronDawg I said *fancy*, and not *fake* :-) so please don't resent back ;-). Things are all about definitions and not real math issues here. In the **context** of DFT, $x[-1]$ simply refers to $x[N-1]$ due to $x[n]$ being circular (periodic) sequence. If you want to make a reference to a **linear** operation on the supplied data of $x[n]$ treated as an aperiodic finite length sequence,you can do it in a number of ways,but the most **elegant** is to use the concept of circular vs linear adjustment on the DFT size N. And finally DFT is DFS and there is no need to re-define it I guess... ;-)

Comment: @CedronDawg The only difference between DFS and DFT is that while DFS uses the concept of infinite length periodic sequences $\tilde{x}[n]$ and $\tilde{X}[k]$, the DFT *assumes* that the data $x[n]$ is finite length but then uses the **modulo-N** arithmetic on every operation it defines to get the exact-same effect as if DFS was used on the data x[n], but avoids the term *infinite length periodic sequence*. Because the computer science does not like the terms **continuous** or **infinite**. That's it, you proces the **base period** of a periodic sequence to achieve DFS results and call it DFT.

Comment: @CedronDawg If you're saying we can _shift_ the slope term to lie within `0` to `N-1`, that's yet to be shown. Now, I've tried various signals, and using `x[0]` and `x[N-1]` as slope indices. I found the mean absolute difference between the finite difference taken via `np.diff`, and inverted from the manipulated frequency domain, to be exactly equal in `float64` both with and without the slope term - which I found strange. I couldn't force the slope term to be non-negligible compared to all other coefficients.

Comment: OLGD, I think the thing giving you trouble is using the np.diff.  Since it drops the leading sample, you are really getting the forward difference.  My answer doesn't deal with the dropped sample case.  Perhaps you should just generate a long signal x[n], calculate y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1], then pick a frame in the middle somewhere and take the respective DFTs, X and Y.  I'm pretty sure those results will match my answer.

Comment: @Fat32 I didn't mean to sound resentful, sorry about that. The DFS thing is of no concern to me, I probably shouldn't have said anything about that. The DFT has no inherent assumption. It assumes nothing about what is outside the frame.  It might be useful for some purposes to assume the signal is a periodic repeat of the frame and I have no problem with that, but that should be stated not presumed. In my frequency formula articles, the assumption is that the signal is a portion of a single pure tone that extends as a pure tone outside the frame.  Different purpose, different assumption.

Comment: @CedronDawg Quick note, it's only a slope term at inversion, _not_ in $Y[k]$, else it's $1/N^2$ at inversion. Think I have some good & bad news for the slope term; might add an answer - but `x[-1]` remains unredeemed.

Comment: Answer unaccepted - everyone is wrong. See my new answer. -- Or maybe I should open a new Q&A at this point - the length of this one is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a detailed answer along the lines of what you propose, we need to be careful about the normalization used in discrete Fourier transform (DFT) and inverse discrete Fourier transform (IDFT):

$$\text{DFT: }\quad X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j 2\pi kn/N}\tag{1}$$
$$\text{IDFT: }\quad x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{j 2 \pi k n / N}\tag{2}$$

Those have a normalization that is directly compatible with `fft` and `ifft` from MATLAB, Octave, NumPy and SciPy. The indexes $k$ and $n$ run from $0$ to $N-1$. (MATLAB and Octave have a different indexing convention, $1$ to $N$.) Then:

$$\begin{array}{c}y[n] = x[n] - x[\operatorname{mod}(n-1, N)]\\
\begin{align}\\
Y &= \operatorname{DFT}\big(y\big)\\
&= \operatorname{DFT}(x*[1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots])\\
&= \operatorname{DFT}(x)\times\operatorname{DFT}([1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots])\\
&= X\times\operatorname{DFT}([1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots])\end{align}\end{array}\tag{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow Y[k]= X[k]\left(1 - e^{-j2\pi k/N}\right),\tag{4}$$

where $\operatorname{mod}$ gives the unsigned remainder, for example $\operatorname{mod}(-1, N) = N - 1$, the symbol $*$ denotes length-$N$ circular convolution and $\times$ denotes multiplication, and all sequences are of length $N$.

Circular convolution in the discrete time domain is exactly equivalent to multiplication in the discrete frequency domain, when DFT and IDFT are used to transform the sequences between the domains. See for example [Circular Convolution - MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-341-discrete-time-signal-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec16.pdf). For "linear" convolution of discrete sequences, there is no such elegant pair of equivalent operations, which makes me think no expression proposed as an answer to the question will ever be fully satisfactory.

Considering input signals that extend to the left of the output range $0 \le n < N$ of IDFT, calculating the [backward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) using modulo indexing is conditionally equal to calculating it without it:

$$x[n] - x[\operatorname{mod}(n-1, N)] = x[n] - x[n-1]\quad\text{conditionally}\tag{5}$$

under the condition that you only calculate it for some of the indexes:

$$0 < n < N,\tag{6}$$

or for $0 \le n < N$ under the condition that there's a hint of periodicity in the signal:

$$x[-1] = x[N-1].\tag{7}$$

A sufficient but not necessary condition that satisfies Eq. 7 is that $x$ is $N$-periodic, which is however prohibited by the signal defined as finite in the question. An example of another condition that satisfies Eq. 7 is $x[-1] = x[N-1] = 0$.

[@CedronDawg's first answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70118/15347) provides a formula which corrects in the frequency domain the error in Eq. 5 if neither condition is satisfied: $Y[k] = X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-j2\pi k/N} \right) -  x[-1] + x[N-1]$. As an alternative derivation, in length-$N$ time domain the correction is an impulse:

$$\begin{align}&\big[x[0] - x[−1] - \big(x[0] - x[N-1]\big),\, 0,\, 0,\, \ldots\big]\\
= &\big[x[N-1] - x[-1],\, 0,\, 0,\, \ldots\big],\end{align}\tag{8}$$

which in frequency domain is a constant (see [DFT Pairs and Properties](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/Discrete_Fourier_Transform_table): pair row 2, property linearity):

$$x[N-1] - x[-1],\tag{9}$$

to be added to all elements of $Y$ calculated by Eq. 4.

For a general $x$, the condition of Eq. 6 for Eq. 5 enables to use a length $N+1$ DFT and IFT to calculate the backward difference, by shifting the input to the DFT one step to the right, and finally by shifting the output from IDFT one step to the left. With forward difference $x[n + 1] - x[n]$, the shift would not be necessary, and I think this matches your discarding of the 0th sample. For a circular convolution implementation of convolution by a finite sequence, using a longer transform is a common trick to avoid the circular effects in a sufficiently large part of the output of the IDFT. For then obtaining the DFT of a partial IDFT output, in particular a one shorter, I don't think there is any shortcut.

We could perhaps re-express the question as: What is the DFT of the length $N-1$ forward difference of $x$ of length $N$, given $x$ and $X_{N-1} = \operatorname{DFT}(x_{N-1})$, a length $N-1$ DFT of the partial sequence $x_{N-1} = \big[x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-2]\big]$? Analogously to Eq. 4 we have:

$$y_{N-1} = x_{N-1}*[-1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0, 0, 1]\tag{10.1}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y_{N-1} = X_{N-1}\times\operatorname{DFT}([-1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0, 0, 1])\tag{10.2}$$
$$\Rightarrow Y_{N-1}[k] = X_{N-1}[k]\big(e^{j2\pi k / (N - 1)} - 1\big),\tag{10.3}$$

where each sequence is of length $N-1$. The desired forward difference $f_{N-1}$ is:

$$f_{N-1} = \big[x[1] - x[0],\, x[2] - x[1],\, \ldots,\, x[N-1] - x[N-2]\big].\tag{11}$$

Eq. 10.1 can be expanded to:

$$y_{N-1} = \big[x[1] - x[0],\, x[2] - x[1],\, \ldots,\, x[0] - x[N-2]\big].\tag{12}$$

By comparing Eqs. 11 and 12, it can be seen that:

$$f_{N-1} = y_{N-1} + \big[\ldots,\, 0,\, 0,\, x[N-1] - x[0]\big],\tag{13}$$

where the sequence in brackets is of length $N-1$. Taking the DFT of both sides of Eq. 13 and applying Eq. 10.3 gives the answer:

$$\begin{align}F_{N-1}[k] &= Y_{N-1}[k] + (x[N-1] - x[0])e^{j2\pi k/(N-1)}\\
&=X_{N-1}[k]\big(e^{j2\pi k / (N - 1)} - 1\big) + (x[N-1] - x[0])e^{j2\pi k/(N-1)}.\end{align}\tag{14}$$

This is the length $N-1$ DFT of the length $N-1$ forward difference of $x$ of length $N$.

Alternatively, you might be interested in the [derivative of the band-limited signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44009/15347) represented by the samples.

Comment: Seem to have nailed it - I'll run some checks to confirm this works in my context.

Comment: A question as simple as DFT{x[n] - x[n-1]} should be answered as simple as $X[k] (1 - e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k})$, and that arguments are modulo-N.;i.e., $x[n-1] = x[(n-1)_N]$ and that $x[-1] = x[N-1]$. Now, I understand that the OP wants to get a **linear** first difference instead of **circular** one, and then the answer should only be modified by adding that $M=N+1$ length cicular difference will be equal to the linear difference. Just as the case of liner vs circular convolution. Nothing else needs to be added. But we all tend to *improve* already perfect answers bu putting more work of us.;-)

Comment: Haven't studied circular in detail yet, can't comment there - but the end-result still fails [properties 1 & 2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70292/50076): `len(Y) == N`, and `Y[0] != sum(x[n] - x[n - 1])`. Prop 2 must hold whether or not $x$ is periodic - but in your answer, `Y[0] == 0`.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon what a long argumentation for something not so deserving it... Of course I have full sympathy and respect for whatever hobby you have, but Olli's answer is **the** one you will get from a dsp guy. I've read your argument on rejecting this answer as anti-derivative is not correct due full recovery of x[n]+C from its first difference (you call dropping a sample). Remember that by invoking a (N+1)-point DFT of x[n],  you place *one zero sample* at the end which means you are setting C=0 so you can solve the DE from the first diference. If C is nonzero then x[n] has no DFT...

Comment: @Fat32 Au contraire, this is a learning exercise of the best kind.  Olli's answer is consistent with "DFT Theory".  And it is blind to my formula.  It is also apparently blind to my frequency formulas (as practitioners would refuse to look at my math because "exact formulas are impossible").  In my attempts to confirm their novelty, I came to the conclusion that most EE profs are posers and don't really understand math.  Sad to say.

Comment: These were the first.  I've found better once since.  All in my articles.  Click on the red author name to see the full list.  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/773.php

Comment: @Fat32 That's _fabricating information_; we have no reason to assume the resulting derivative is what it is with a zero, a pi, or a TREE(3) inserted anywhere. Finite difference loses information - it _must_; there are infinitely many $x[n]$ with the same $x'[n]$, the transform is non-invertible. It _becomes_ invertible if we preserve "C", but we don't - `DFT(x[n] - x[n-1])` yields `N - 1` coefficients, and they cannot encode this information. Even if I grant an exception to this, `Y[0] == 0` remains a fallacy (unless padding _both_ endpoints, which is even more fabrication).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Within your stated paradigm, the missing information is x[-1], which would be called initial value or analogous to "+C".  "DFT theory" "assumes" x[-1] = x[N-1].  harris, in his seminal windows paper, uses "essentially considered as".  You might think those are synonyms, but I see the dividing line of acceptability between them.

Comment: @CedronDawg The +C is the _dropped sample_, not x[-1]. In fact, we can recover x[n] entirely from x'[n] by knowing any one sample from the original x[n], dropped or not. x[-1] is fundamentally problematic; we're describing frame A with information outside it. -- Reading your updated answer.

Comment: Well Olli, I've cited them frequently in answers when pertinent to the solution.  You asked which formulas, I gave you the link, so my primary motivation here was to satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo This. I've taken this approach in StackOverflow - doesn't disappoint. Not only do you farm rep, but can start discussions you otherwise wouldn't on a blog. (And no, dropping a link in an answer isn't equivalent; the link itself must be the subject of the Q&A. What you actually include in the Q&A depends on whether you seek people to actually go to the site, or just to spread knowledge).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Sorry, like my answer, I'm not covering the dropped sample scenario.  The dropped sample(s) in np.diff are done precisely to address this issue rather than assuming a rotation.  The dropped sample is indeed x[0]-x[-1].

Comment: @CedronDawg This isn't even about np.diff any more, it's just a necessity of the transform that is the finite difference over the analysis frame 0 to N-1. If y[0] describes x[0] - x[-1], of course you're right, but if we ever needed to do this, we'd just expand the analysis frame a sample left - and back to square one.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Seems to me I said something vaguely similar to that in my first answer concerning the dropped sample scenario.  The latest code sample confirms the equations numerically, and hopefully Fat32 has learned a new technique.  There are a lot of "what this is about" being juggled in the air right now.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Nobody has to answer your nonsesence concerns here. DFT is about **FINITE LENGTH** sequences, (i.e., known to be **ZERO** outside of a domain of support). And indeed if a sequence is known to be finite length, then it can be fully recovered from it's first difference x[n]-x[n-1], there's nothing suprising, restricting, or violating about it? Ex: x[n] = [2,3,4] for n=[0,1,2] => x[n]-x[n-1] = [2,1,1]... now can you recover x[n]? YES! becuase it's FINITE LENGTH. If it were infinite length, then you would ask what x[-1] was? Or you would invent the *dropping* fun..??

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon DTFT (discrete-time Fourier transform), on the other hand  deals with sequences of **INFINITE LENGTH** (as well as finite length), and in that case, you cannot recover a sequence x[n] from its first difference **WITHOUT** an additional piece of information. That additional piece of information simply becomes as  x[n] = 0 for some n<n0, when x[n] is a FINITE length sequence. That's sufficient to close this ridiculus discussion here...

Comment: @Fat32 I expected better of the supposed DSP experts here, then again experts falling apart when it comes to the fundamentals of their domain isn't much news to me. See my latest reply under my second answer.

Comment: @CedronDawg you **developed** a SYSTEMATIC HABIT of putting nonesense fancy math here... And you abuse here by covering your nonsense claims behind those fancy math that nobody *understands*... please stop doing that.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon the example should be x[n] = [2,3,4] and x[n]-x[n-1] =[2,1,1,-4]

Comment: @Fat32 I would say "rigorous" rather than "fancy".  I've been pondering what you have meant by that since you first said it, still not sure.  Well, a perception of nonsense can be due to not understanding or a nonsensical proposition.  At least you didn't say "not understandable".  harris, in the paragraphs before my last reference speaks of having two viewpoints and switching between them.  It works.  I would think you would welcome a new viewpoint and strive to understand it.

Comment: @CedronDawg Rigorous? Are you serious? These are just fancy and useless, sorry to say... Not even re-inventing the wheel ;-) Your *method* is not something new too ;-)

Comment: @CedronDawg I really wonder how you *mathematicians* rigorously describe *differentiation* on an **integer** domain set, as you did below. By just freely assuming that *n* is a continuous variable? Is that the level of rigor? Sometimes it works but mostly it's awkward.

Comment: @CedronDawg enough for today. I have said all about this question... and don't want to hear more.

Comment: @Fat32  [I wrote this before your last comment so I am not going to throw it away, you can read it another day] Serious? Mostly.  Resentful?  Heck no.  Concerning the formula in my first answer whether it is new, or new to you, nor neither, ain't no thing.  If you happen to have a reference to an occurence that would be cool.  Actually, "let's make in continuous" is quite proper here as the RHS of the first is already continuous, it is the LHS which introduces the discreteness.  As rigorous as possible, not even close.  Nobody I think, including me, wants to go full Real Analysis.

Comment: @Fat32 I accept your proposition. Now, let's stand on a very tall cliff, and take one step off of it. Since our initial vertical position is 9000, that's also our vertical velocity (x'[0] = x[0] - 0, right?). Congrats, we faceplanted at 10x the terminal velocity. -- This is what your math implies, nothing less. x'[0] has nothing to do with the rate of change of x, but its initial value. If you find this description meaningful or useful, so be it - I seek something without magical consequences for the nature of reality or information.

Comment: @CedronDawg You still side by x'(n)? That's due much "works only assuming X, Y, and Z", else you've invented an infinite compression algorithm and solved world's energy problems.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Not sure what you mean by that, and I've got some other stuff to do.  The math is the math, it says what it says.  The code is the code, it does what it does.  That's pretty objective.  How we describe it is a fount of endless squabbling.  That's pretty subjective.  .......... It is also the crucible of deeper understanding.

Comment: @CedronDawg You've contributed enough, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @CedronDawg Ok, I do also freely apply calculus operators (limit, diff etc.) on discrete-time *sequences* to get a *working result* in some circumstances; the value of a sinc(n) pulse at the origin is a nice example. I said it because of your *rigour* claim. DSP is not about formal analysis, though it benefits a lot from its results. DSP is about coming up with intuitive, creative, efficient, practical, reliable, accurate, and robust solutions to electrical (or some other) engineering problems implemented in discrete-time hardware & software. Because otherwise it won't make sense.

Comment: Err, a small typo in my code. I have a grand announcement... **It WORKS!** Excellent work, Olli.

Comment: Though, two issues: (1) we were to have a relation from $X_N$, not $X_{N-1}$; (2) we shouldn't require the original signal as an input to compute $F_{N-1}$ (and we can't recover it from $X_{N-1}$). Since you've worked out an expression with 1 fewer coefficient ($X_{N-1}$), you in a way solved a harder problem, so a workaround to (1) and (2) seems possible.

Comment: $X_{N-1} = \text{DFT}(\text{IDFT}(x)[\text{:-1}])$ is possible, but doesn't quite count as the idea is to directly relate the frequency spectrum of `x` with that of `DIFF(x)` (magnitude, phase, etc) - but for a long enough or padded `x` it's a close equivalent.

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut to "directly relate the frequency spectrum of x with that of DIFF(x)", as you express it. The main computation would amount to taking the IDFT and then a one-shorter DFT, of which I say the same thing in the answer. That computation would be equivalent to band-limited resampling, which is a quite thoroughly researched area of digital signal processing, and I doubt there is anything new to be found there, math or computation-wise, that would also be applicable to the present task.

Comment: I see. Still, something came of all this: with endpoints equal, "differentiating" shifts phase linearly, and modulates amplitude sinusoidally. If unequal, it also depends on their difference.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit:  This answer is based on x[n] being the input signal (likely sampled from a continuous differentiable function), which was my misinterpretion of the OP's question, and that what was being sought was a transform from the spectrum of the input signal to the spectrum of the linear first difference.  If one desires the spectrum of the circular first difference within the analysis frame there is no need for the slope term.  Furthermore, it can clearly be seen from the formula that the DC bin of the circluar difference spectrum will be zero.]

This is a different approach than Olli's doing it straight from the definition and not assuming a N periodic signal.

$$
\begin{aligned}
Y[k] &=  \text{DFT}(x[n] - x[n-1]) \\
&= \text{DFT}(x[n]) - \text{DFT}(x[n-1]) \\
&= X[k] - \text{DFT}(x[n-1]) \\
&= X[k] - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n-1] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn }  \\
&= X[k] - \sum_{m=-1}^{N-2} x[m] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k(m+1)}  \\
&= X[k] - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \sum_{m=-1}^{N-2} x[m] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}km}  \\
&= X[k] - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k}\left[ \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} x[m] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}km} + x[-1]e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} - x[N-1] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k(N-1)} \right] \\
&= X[k] - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k}\left[ X[k] + x[-1] e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} - x[N-1] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k(N-1)} \right] \\
&= X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right) -  \left[  x[-1] - x[N-1] e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k(N-1)}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right] \\
&= X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right) -  x[-1] + x[N-1]  \\
\end{aligned}
$$

For a N periodic signal $x[-1] = x[N-1] $ so the result becomes:

$$
Y[k] = X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right)
$$

Considering the normalization is important.  I used the conventional unnormalized forward DFT definition.  Using the (more proper,IMO) 1/N normalization, as implied by the OP's definition of the inverse DFT, the expression becomes:

$$
Y[k] = X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right)  + \frac{x[N-1]-x[-1]}{N} 
$$

The last term now clearly becomes a slope calculation.

---

In response to OverLordGoldDragon's comment.  Using the conventional normalization:

$$ 
x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk }
$$

Let's make it continuous.

$$ 
x(n) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk }
$$

Take the derivative in respect to n.

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dn} (n) &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk } \left(i \frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{N^2} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} i k X[k] e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk } \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So, your initial assertion isn't quite correct, it does apply to the DFT for the continuous derivative.

By the chain rule:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dn} \cdot \frac{dn}{dt} $$

The differential you are using for an approximation for the derivative is not the best one as it has a half sample shift included.  Generally you would prefer $(x[n+1]-x[n-1])/2$.  This stays centered and doesn't "amplify noise" in the higher frequency range.

The comment is a little off too.
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right) &= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{N}k} \left( e^{i\frac{\pi}{N}k} - e^{-i\frac{\pi}{N}k} \right) \\
&= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{N} k} 2i \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{N}k \right) \\
&= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{N} k} 2 e^{i \frac{\pi}{2} } \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{N}k \right) \\
&= e^{-i\left( \frac{\pi}{N} k - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) } 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{N}k \right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

so

$$ \left| \left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right) \right| = 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{N}k \right) $$

and

$$ \arg \left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{N} k + \frac{\pi}{2} = - \frac{\pi}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{2k}{N} \right) $$

Switching gears, note that for $k=0$

$$ Y[0] = \frac{x[N-1]-x[-1]}{N} $$

So the DC component of your differential is the average slope over your frame, as expected.

I don't read text books, so I can't really address that. Interesting is not always synonymous with useful.

I'm self taught, then I do online research to confirm my findings.  What is a wonder to me is that my frequency formulas, which are the first to achieve exactness, aren't in the curriculum yet either.

---

Puzzle solved.  Duh.

Unless you center around zero, so you are using $k=-1$ instead of $k=N-1$, the derivative will be of the higher frequency interpolation (equivalent to the derivative of the DTFT at that point).

This is similar to the "Fluffy Cloud" case here:  [How to get Fourier coefficients to draw any shape using DFT?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59068/how-to-get-fourier-coefficients-to-draw-any-shape-using-dft/59085#59085)

---

I think part of my confusion is that you are using (upon rereading) the extended inverse DFT as x[n], thus x[-1] can be calculated and will match x[N-1], while in your code you generate a signal x[n] from scratch.

Define

$$ y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1] $$

and

$$ Y[k] = DFT(y[n]) $$

Your code "drops a sample", while Olli's and my answers employ x[-1].  Olli's answer assumes periodicity (go ahead accept it), mine doesn't (thinking you were working with a raw signal).  I don't think it is appropriate to "drop a sample" as the np.diff call does.  If you do, you should reframe the problem on the domain of 1 to N-1 as being 0 to M-1, where M = N-1, then you have the equivalent situation as not having dropped a sample.

When your "drop a sample" it changes the DFT definitions invalidating my first two lines.

Be a bit patient, and I'll clarify the puzzle remark.

---

Without a lot of explanation, here is the "puzzle solved".  Note, that if x were to be interpolated using the upper k values as positive frequencies, there would be a whole lot of oscillations between the plotted points.  Thus, so would Y.

Rescaling is muddled by the $ 2\pi $ factor on t and the $\frac{dn}{dt}$ factor, so I didn't bother cluttering the code as it isn't salient to the issue at hand.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#=========================================================
def main():

        N = 128
        
        t = np.linspace( 0, 1, N, False )
        x = np.cos( 2 * np.pi * t )
        
        X = np.fft.fft( x )

        plt.plot( x )
        plt.show()
        
        Y = np.zeros( N, dtype='complex' )
        
        for k in range( N ):
          Y[k] = X[k] * 1j * k

        y = np.fft.ifft( Y )
        
        plt.plot( y.real )
        plt.plot( y.imag )
        plt.show()
        

        Z = np.zeros( N, dtype='complex' )
        
        H = N >> 1
        
        for k in range( -H, H ):
          if k >= 0:
             Z[k]   = X[k]   * 1j * k
          else:
             Z[k+N] = X[k+N] * 1j * k

        z = np.fft.ifft( Z )
        
        plt.plot( z.real )
        plt.plot( z.imag )
        plt.show()


#=========================================================
main()
```

Here is the last plot:

[image]

Here is a test program for the formula:

```
import numpy as np

#=============================================================================
def main():

        L  = 10000              # Length of Signals
        F  = 100                # Frame location 

        N  = 16                 # Frame Size = DFT Sample Count
        
        P = np.zeros( L )       # Position
        D = np.zeros( L )       # Difference
        
        for n in range( L ):
          P[n] = 1.2 + 0.3 * n + 0.045 * n * n

        for n in range( 1, L ):
          D[n] = P[n] - P[n-1]
          
        x = P[F:F+N]  
        y = D[F:F+N]
        
        X = np.fft.fft( x ) / N
        Y = np.fft.fft( y ) / N
        
        Z = np.zeros( N, dtype=complex )
        
        C = ( x[N-1] - P[F-1] ) / N

        for k in range( N ):
          Z[k] = X[k] * ( 1 - np.exp( -1j * ( 2.0 * np.pi / N ) * k ) ) + C
        
        for n in range( N ):
          print( "%2d %10.6f %10.6f   %10.6f %10.6f" % \
               ( n, Y[n].real, Y[n].imag, Z[n].real, Z[n].imag ) )
        

#=============================================================================
main()
```

Here are the results:

```
 0   9.930000   0.000000     9.930000   0.000000
 1  -0.045000   0.226230    -0.045000   0.226230
 2  -0.045000   0.108640    -0.045000   0.108640
 3  -0.045000   0.067347    -0.045000   0.067347
 4  -0.045000   0.045000    -0.045000   0.045000
 5  -0.045000   0.030068    -0.045000   0.030068
 6  -0.045000   0.018640    -0.045000   0.018640
 7  -0.045000   0.008951    -0.045000   0.008951
 8  -0.045000   0.000000    -0.045000  -0.000000
 9  -0.045000  -0.008951    -0.045000  -0.008951
10  -0.045000  -0.018640    -0.045000  -0.018640
11  -0.045000  -0.030068    -0.045000  -0.030068
12  -0.045000  -0.045000    -0.045000  -0.045000
13  -0.045000  -0.067347    -0.045000  -0.067347
14  -0.045000  -0.108640    -0.045000  -0.108640
15  -0.045000  -0.226230    -0.045000  -0.226230
```

Comment: "The response part of your edit should've been a comment".  Nah, it was too long for a comment, I figured you'd see it anyway, or be notified of a change in an answer.

Comment: Your continuous derivation appears invalid; [tried](https://pastebin.com/k4Aq4hhA) it with a simple cosine - inverse yields negative of derivative in real part, but also an entire imaginary part (which should be zero), and normalization is also off. Problem seems to be in assuming $x[n] \rightarrow x(n)$; an inverse "inverts" the forward transformation, and a forward transform of a continuous signal would have $N=\infty$.

Comment: How's it work with DTFT then? Not exactly sure, but I'd explain it as the _encoding_ inserting as much information (i.e. $\omega$) as is decoded (inverted), and can thus be discretized arbitrarily. To contrary, the DFT of a signal demands as many coefficients as the number of points in the signal - whereas your inverse assumes a finite (or simply different) $N$, hence not decoding what was encoded. -- Lastly, it absurdly implies ability for _infinite compression_, as you're restoring an infinite $x(n)$ from $N$ finite coefficients.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon This is a puzzler, I am looking at it.  For the DTFT, you will have to center the spectrum on zero as -1 is not the same as N-1 in the interpolation.  It helps that you used a degenerate case.  One small point, I've added a ",False" parameter to your linspace call to not include the endpoint.  Funny, since you mentioned that as an issue earlier.

Comment: Good catch, and it is an issue; endpoints are akin to boundary conditions and shouldn't be treated lightly. The discrete derivative does accurately differentiate every case I've tried so far, but the slope addition seems to be a redundancy; DFT already assumes the input signal to be N-periodic, and where would we fetch $x[-1]$ anyway? The indices also should run from `1` to `N - 1` instead of from `0`, but I'm wondering how to 'justify' this restriction mathematically.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Sigh, there is so much wrong in this comment I don't know where to begin. The DFT does not assume the input signal to be N-periodic. See the comments on RB-Js long answer here to his "periodic deniers" claim: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70035  If the input signal were periodic then x[-1] = x[N-1].  The fact that this presumption is generally incorrect is why I answered differently than Olli, to include this.  Usually, your analysis frame is a subset of the signal so the actual value is obtainable.  More later.

Comment: Read it - if anything, I entirely agree with you; I presumed what people _mean_ by "assumes" is what you described there - but indeed the DFT couldn't care less about a signal's periodicity, so long as it's finite. What I meant is the _extension_ (better term than "extrapolate" as latter implies approximating) is periodic in both domains, enabling various aliasing and symmetry analysis. The phrase could really use a reformulation.

Comment: However, I'm unsure what you mean by "x[-1] = x[N - 1] is generally incorrect". If we agree the signal extends to left and right as repeated copies of itself (i.e. periodically) upon inversion, then x[-1] _must_ be x[N-1]; have a counterexample?

Comment: so Ced, i read through your entire answer, including the updated edits.  what does a DFT periodicity denier do with $x[-1]$?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon says: //but indeed the DFT couldn't care less about a signal's periodicity, so long as it's finite.//  $$ $$ that's bullshit.  again, what if you multiply the DFT of $x[n]$ (which we call "$X[k]$") with $e^{j 2 \pi d k/N}$ (where $d$ is an integer)?  you will find that the DFT ***very much cares*** about periodicity.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing, and based on C. Dawg's answer, discarding the slope addition, the effect on magnitude and phase are

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
  |X[k]|         & \rightarrow M|X[k]| \\
  \angle{(X[k])} & \rightarrow \phi + \angle{(X[k])} \\
\end{aligned} 
$$

where

$$
\begin{aligned}
   M    &= 2 \left| \sin{\left( \pi \frac{k}{N} \right)} \right| \\
   \phi &= \frac{\pi}{N}(k\ \text{mod}\ N- N/2) \cdot \lceil k\ \text{mod}\ N \rceil
\end{aligned}
$$

The $\lceil k\ \text{mod}\ N \rceil$ sets $\phi$ to 0 when $k$ is a multiple of $N$, using the convention $\angle(0 + 0i)=0$. Graphically,

[image]

Note that the unwrapped $\phi$ is a straight line, so the time-domain effect is a time shift.

---

**iDFT**: indices should run from `1` to `N - 1`, as the finite difference drops a sample. Also, the slope addition is redundant; the inverse DFT extends the original signal N-periodicically, so it's zeroed.

Python implementation below; tested with random normal noise, which is a sort of "un-nicest" signal - mean absolute error is `1e-16`, which is simply float error.

```
def d_idft(coef):
    N = len(coef)
    coef = coef * (1 - np.exp(-1j * 2 * np.pi / N * np.arange(N)))
    return np.fft.ifft(coef)[1:]
```

---

**APPENDUM**: below are my comments, trimmed from discussions below answers, summarizing important points/caveats, and contradicting the accepted answer. Didn't include other speakers as it'd get really long, but shown excerpts should hint at what's being responded to.

---

**Slope term**:

> "discrete derivative meaningless" - this isn't about the discrete derivative, but about x[n] - x[n-1], whatever interpretation it may hold. Sometimes it's as good as a derivative, other times it's exact in the sense of undoing cumsum, yet other times virtually useless, but point is it's some time-domain transformation whose frequency-domain equivalent we seek

> As to your discrete derivation; since there isn't an x[-1] to begin with, the only alternative is the inverse, which equals x[N-1], so again it drops.

> It's an overcomplete representation. To encode an N-1 point derivative, it requires N+1 points of data (the original N coefficients plus x[-1]). The DFT is a complete encoding; we can invert it and differentiate in time domain without ever needing x[-1], so same must be possible working purely in the frequency domain.

> Consider a counterexample; suppose we don't take x[-1] to come from inversion; then it must be of the original signal, which we framed, but where x[-1] exists. Suppose x[0] to x[N-1] are all zeros, and x[-1] = 100^100 ...

---

**"DFT assumes the input is periodic"**

> I said the *inversion*, when extended, is periodic; the DTF describes only the portion of the *original signal* which was fed - not more, not less. We can extend in time domain to analyze aliasing etc., but can't make any description about the original signal outside of the frame.

> The root of the debate is a lack of sufficient *definitions*, i.e. what "assumes" even means; you and I see it as non-fundamental to the transform itself, yet we also agree some contexts / operations demand periodicity.

---

**Continuous derivation ($x(n)$)**

> An inverse "inverts" the forward transformation, and a forward transform of a continuous signal would have $N=\infty$. DTFT: the encoding inserts as much information (i.e. ω) as is decoded (inverted), and can thus be discretized arbitrarily. To contrary, the DFT of a signal demands as many coefficients as the number of points in the signal - whereas your inverse assumes a finite (or simply different) N, hence not decoding what was encoded.

> It absurdly implies ability for *infinite compression*, as you're restoring an infinite x(n) from N finite coefficients.

> But what if we simply discretize, $x'(n)\rightarrow x'[n]$? Then the compression argument falls. Your expression handled a linear chirp fairly well in terms of shape, comparing with np.diff, and since latter indeed isn't a "true" derivative, it's not obvious which is "more correct". There's math work to be done to justify continuous-differentiating and then discretizing again, but maybe it can be done after all.

**Edit 1/10/2020**: indeed, it [can be](http://webhome.auburn.edu/%7Ejzl0097/teaching/math_8970/Tadmor_86.pdf) done, and is interpreted as a *discretized* (not *discrete*) derivative of the *trigonometric interpolation* of $x[n]$ (*not* of $x(n)$), and the 'nicer' such interpolation fits $x[n]$, the more accurate the derivative. Stranger yet, discretized FT and DFT can work together [sometimes](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/0.05/ssqueezepy/wavelet_transforms.py#L468).

However, Cedron's derivation still normalizes wrongly (but his *code* is correct); strangely, $x'[n]$ is found via *discrete* iFT (iDFT) of *discretized* FT derivative, so the extra $2\pi / N$ doesn't belong. ... or maybe it belongs under a different set of assumptions, but none I've yet come across.

Comment: I'm afraid you are a bit incorrect here as well.  First, it would be nicer if you used $Y[k]$ for your differential as Olli and I did to distinquish it from the original DFT.  Second, you are still missing the proper factor in your sine argument.  $\sin(k/2)$ would have a ton of oscillations across your range.  $\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{N}k \right)$ has the argument going from 0 to $\pi$ as $k$ goes from 0 to $N$.  Likewise the arg will range from $ -\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ without any wrapping.

Comment: @CedronDawg Right, I had the k/2 fixed - didn't actually derive it, but tossed |1 - e^(-ix)| to WolframAlpha and forgot about everything else. As for $Y[k]$, I am symbolically showing the direct effect on the non-differentiated $X[k]$. Also good lead on the alternative derivative; I'm going by Python's Numpy's implementation, which may not necessarily be best - but for this Q&A we rather finish the started.

Comment: @CedronDawg Also, $k$ goes from $0$ to $N-1$ in one period, and the $\angle (0 + 0i)$ case needs accounting for.

Comment: When talking about the general behavior, whether you include N or not isn't a big deal.  So, yeah, you should have one lobe of the sine function, starting at 0, almost reaching 0 again at the end at N-1.  Not two lobes as you show.  Similar with the angle case, indeed arg(0) is undefined, but I think you will find a limit argument will quell any discomfort.  Just put an open circle in the zero position and you'll be good.

Comment: I didn't notice your scale.  The graph is correct and I did my first comment incorrectly.  The arg in my equation goes from $ -\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $ -3 \frac{\pi}{2}$.  You can add $\pi$ (instead of $2\pi$) and still be correct because of the absolute value on the magnitude part.  So, it goes from $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $ - \frac{\pi}{2}$ as shown in your graph.

Comment: We have gotten the chat prompt under my answer, so I am continuing here.  I don't agree the signal extends itself on either side periodically or that that should be assumed.  That only happens in special cases, so in general when placing a frame on a portion of a signal you can not assume that $ x[-1] = x[N-1] $, nor should you.  You can count on that being true in the frequency domain $ X[k] = X[k+N] $ as well as on the extended inverse DFT of the spectrum, but you should not say, nor imply that, about the signal itself.

Comment: @CedronDawg I said the _inversion_, when extended, is periodic; the DTF describes only the portion of the _original_ signal which was fed - not more, not less. We can extend in time domain to analyze aliasing etc., but can't make any description about the original signal outside of the frame. -- and chat prompt is fine, just means a mod will collapse everything and we get more space, which I don't mind.

Comment: @CedronDawg There's another problem with the slope; it's an *overcomplete* representation. To encode an `N-1` point derivative, it requires `N+1` points of data (the original `N` coefficients plus `x[-1]`). The DFT is a _complete_ encoding; we can invert it and differentiate in time domain without ever needing `x[-1]`, so same must be possible working purely in the frequency domain. Must and does; again, the DFT describes only _the frame that was fed_, that includes the derivative. The slope term won't tell us anything about what happens outside.

Comment: I think your verbage was clunky.  This is kind of the root cause of the confusion.  The "signal" you get upon inversion, when extended, is not necessarily "the signal" you started with.  They will match in the interval.  I have no doubt that you (or RB-J) understand what the math does.  So when I said "x[-1] = x[N - 1] is generally incorrect", I am talking about "the signal" not the extended inverse of the spectrum.

Comment: @CedronDawg Right, it is what I'm saying, but RB-J asserts an assumption on the _input_ itself, where I disagree. To finish previous comment; if you still disagree, it'd help to see an example where excluding the slope term yields different results than directly differentiating the framed signal.

Comment: And that is where I disagree as well.  The inclusion of the x[-1] in my answer was in response to your "dropped sample".  I didn't realize that you meant the frame was shrunk (as per the np call).  I think you can rework my answer with different limits on the summation and substitute in x[0] and (N-1) for x[-1] and N, respectively.

Comment: @CedronDawg Alright, that's on me for ambiguity - if we're staying within `0` to `N - 1` then we should be good to go; in fact as with the regular iDFT we don't need to pass the original signal, as we can use the already-inverted x[0] and x[N-1]. However, I don't see how you'd obtain x[0] and x[N-1] in the sum, and x[-1] seems appropriate as it cancels with x[N-1] in the extension - in fact including this slope _worsens_ reconstruction error for some signals I tried, though very slightly. -- Also unsure which "puzzle" was solved, surely not $x'(n)$.

Comment: We should be good to go.  I think this has been hashed out sufficiently, see my latest followup.

Answer (score 1):

Response to RB-J's comments under my other answer:

"what does a DFT periodicity denier do with x[−1]?"

"what if you multiply the DFT of x[n] (which we call "X[k]") with ej2πdk/N (where d is an integer)? you will find that the DFT very much cares about periodicity. – "

And similar from [Making the units of a analytically calculated PSD consistent with the units of an FFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70035/making-the-units-of-a-analytically-calculated-psd-consistent-with-the-units-of-a)

"//the DFT does not consider what the signal is outside the frame// ... never? ---okay @CedronDawg, what does the DFT "consider" when you multiply X[k] with ej2πdk/N where d∈Z? (all of the X[k] for 0≤k<N.) – robert bristow-johnson 4 hours ago "

Okay, let's start with a signal with lots and lots of samples.  Suppose I want to analyze a section of it with N samples in it.  To do so, I will establish an analysis frame.  This means re-indexing the samples so that the first sample of my analysis frame is at index 0.  Since I intend to take a DFT on this section, I can also call it a DFT frame.

This is not the same thing as "windowing".  I could also define a rectangle window function having ones for all the samples in my section, and zeroes everywhere else.  The window function is indexed on the underlying indexing, it does not establish a new indexing frame.

If I wanted to, I could also define a window function relative to my analysis frame.  A rectangle window spanning my frame would be inert/moot in terms of taking the DFT.  You can consider the DFT definition as having an implicit window like this, but it is not part of the definition.  If it were the unnormalized definition would be:

$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} 1 \cdot x[n] \cdot e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N} kn } $$

So, if the section is not at the start of the signal, $x[-1]$ would refer to the sample just prior to my analysis frame.  If the section is at the start of the signal then the correct answer would be that $x[-1]$ is undefined.  If one had to make an assumption about it, the most logical answer would be a value of zero.

Now, suppose we take the DFT of this section which yields $ X[k] $ values for $ 0 <= k < N $.  Values outside this range can also be evaluated by the defintion and will result in a periodic spectrum with a period of N.  This may not be the fundamental period, but that is irrelevant to this discussion.

We are now at the starting point of the OP's question (something I misunderstood at first).

Given the values of $X[k]$ we can apply the inverse DFT and reproduce the $x[n]$ values for $ 0 <= n < N $, the samples within the analysis frame.  As with the spectrum, the formula also can be evaluated for $n$ values outside the analysis frame.  Likewise, the resulting values will form a periodic sequence with period N.  There is absolutely no reason to assume, assert, or define that these extended values should match the original signal values outside the analysis frame.  If you wish to label that as denial, well ....

It is also impossible, given just the $X[k]$ values to determine what the original $x[-1]$ value is.  The value obtained by extending the inverse DFT will be the same as $x[N-1]$.  Again, there is no foundation to stipulate, assume, assert, maintain, or proclaim that this matches the original signal value.

Suppose now that I multiply/twist up/modulate the spectrum using a factor of $ e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} dk } $.  Okay, let's do the math.

$$ Z[k] = X[k] \cdot e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} dk } $$

Take the inverse DFT:

$$
\begin{aligned}
z[n] &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} Z[k] \cdot e^{ i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk } \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \cdot e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N} dk } \cdot e^{ i \frac{2\pi}{N} nk } \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \cdot e^{ i \frac{2\pi}{N} (n+d)k } \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $ m = n + d $ so $ n = m - d $.

$$
z[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \cdot e^{ i \frac{2\pi}{N} mk } = x[m \text{ mod } N] = x[ ( n + d ) \text{ mod } N]
$$

The end result is that the samples in the analysis frame have been rotated by $d$ samples.

As above, $z[n]$ can be extended using the inverse DFT definition outside the analysis frame forming an N periodic sequence.  There is even less rationale to assume that those values will match the original signal.

The OP's question was suppose that $ y[n] = x[n]-x[n-1] $, can you find $Y[k]$ from $X[k]$ without going through the taking the inverse DFT, taking the difference, and then taking the DFT.

The OP stated that $x[n]$ came from the inverse DFT of $X[k]$, whereas I mistakenly assumed the original $x[n]$ was known.

Then answer was given elegantly by Olli.  And derived from definition in my answer.  The condition that $x[-1]= x[N-1]$ is met for the extended reconstructed signal.

Thus spoke this periodicity denier.

Comment: This is great - we're almost doing research here with this 'debate'. Maybe I should dedicate a Q&A to it, though, as we're going quite a bit off topic.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Actually I consider it a huge waste of my time.  However, if it can drive a stake in the heart of the incredibly misleading assertion that "The DFT assumes the signal is periodic" for at least one person, it was worth it.
$$ $$
I hope you can see that RB-J's "challenge" is pertinent to your question.  The value of $X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right)$ can be seen as the DFT of the original signal minus the original signal rotated by one sample.

Comment: Can relate with your disposition, but mind that we're dealing with mathematics and there's no room for subjective disagreement; everything can be resolved _exactly_. The root of the debate is a lack of sufficient _definitions_, i.e. what "assumes" even means; you and I see it as non-fundamental to the transform itself, yet we also agree some contexts / operations demand periodicity. Explaining this, and explicitly clarifying when periodicity does and does not apply, may create a world-first complete primer on this topic (at least the freely-accessible one).

Comment: Puzzle not solved; try `x = np.random.randn(N)`. I'm unsure you followed my argument from information standpoint; your derivation _implies absurdities_. It's not a math typo, it's literally impossible.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon That's mighty praise, but I doubt it deserves it.  Two points to emphasize though:
$$ $$
1. Definitions are important
$$ $$
2. If you can't derive an assertion from definitions then you don't really understand it
$$ $$
I'd also say there is room for subjectivity in Mathematics in the form of unproven conjectures and any results derived by assuming their truth (or falsehood).   I would use the term "exhibit periodicity" rather than "demand periodicity".

Comment: Well, okay, let's say unstated premises rather than a definitional issue.  Taking a derivative on a discrete set of values is meaningless.  Taking the derivative of a differentiable interpolation function is possible.  The "trigonometric interpolation function" is differentiable.  So the derivative value you get at the sample locations is merely the derivative of the interpolation function.  Of course, there is a wide choice of differentiable interpolation functions, so which you choose is a subjective decision.

Comment: "The OP stated that x[n] came from the inverse DFT of X[k], whereas I mistakenly assumed the original x[n] was known" - no, I didn't, but this shouldn't matter. -- As for all else; I'm not sure arguments along the lines of "manipulate frequency this and that way" are always meaningful, or relevant to what "assumes periodicity" is supposed to mean. Indeed, it can be _useful_ to analyze effects of said modifications in these terms, e.g. circular convolution yielding time-domain aliasing due to overflow, but that's nothing to do with "input must be periodic for DFT to work".

Comment: "discrete derivative meaningless" - this isn't about the discrete derivative, but about `x[n] - x[n-1]`, _whatever interpretation it may hold_. Sometimes it's as good as a derivative, other times it's exact in the sense of undoing `cumsum`, yet other times virtually useless, but point is it's some time-domain transformation whose frequency-domain equivalent we seek - and we can't do $x(n)$ as that implies infinite compression.

Comment: As to your discrete derivation; since there isn't an x[-1] to begin with, the closest (or rather the _only_) alternative is the inverse, which equals x[N-1], so again it drops. Again, the DFT "knows" nothing outside the analysis frame. Then there's the "overcompleteness" issue. Also, consider a counterexample; suppose we _don't_ take x[-1] to come from inversion; then it must be of the original signal, which we framed, but where x[-1] exists. Suppose x[0] to x[N-1] are all zeros, and x[-1] = 100^100 ... 3.6 Roentgen.

Comment: Damn chat prompt again.  (No I don't like disturbing the mods).  Perhaps for a discussion you can post something at https://www.dsprelated.com/forums.  The "puzzle solved" pertained to the derivative question in your opening sentence.  The differential question pertains to the $x[n] -x[n-1]$ aspect.  Did you not say "where $x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{j2\pi kn/N}$" in the question?  If so, and taken at face value, $x[n]$ is the periodic extension sequence, not the original signal from whence $X[k]$ was presumably obtained.

Comment: They ought to give us the [option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137584/612423). I usually avoid non-SE forums as they tend to house an inferior knowledgepool and responsiveness - so suppose eventually I'll get back to this topic and we'll have more space to straighten matters in a Q&A. Now, to your answer: I'll accept, but only if you remove or note the following: the slope term is necessarily zero; the continuous derivation is invalid. If you disagree, we need to make more space somehow ... perhaps below my question?

Comment: I would say the knowledge pool at dsprelated is a stark exception to your rule. It is much slower moving and not as broad, but quite deep. Many of the best posters here frequent there as well (including RB-J). fred harris even pops by (though he hasn't commented on my windows article)  dsprelated.com/showarticle/1365.php  Go ahead give the accept to Olli.  The clarifications you seek are amply available to any one who takes the effort to follow the comments.  It has been my observation that upvotes and acceptances in this forum aren't very reflective of the quality of answers as I see them.

Comment: Alright, noted @dsprelated. But why Olli's? You've given by far the most comprehensive answer _and_ comments discussion in this Q&A; I'd have learned far less if not for our back & forths. Only you can bear the mark of acceptance. At the least add a note sentence about those two points, probably on top of the answer - else I can do it myself in the question.

Comment: Off-topic; do you have or know of an article on a visual or otherwise intuitive explanation of "time-domain conv. <=> freq-domain mult."? Could open a Q&A on this - not looking for an equation salad, already ate it.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Off-topic???!!!! Honestly I am not the best person to answer that.  I don't really think in those terms.  Perhaps you should post that as a new question.  Maybe I'll opine more in a while.  Very abstractly, Olli painted the ceiling, and I built the scaffolding.  To get a feel for it, I would recommend that you redo my derivation and generalize the "slope term" for any $ y[n] = \sum_{k}  h[n-k] \cdot x[n] $ in terms of $h$.  For the OP, h[0] = 1, h[1] = -1.  Keep in mind, index order is what distinguishes a convolution from a sliding weighted average.

Comment: [Done](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70324/50076), though I'll be less active the coming days - stuff to do. Briefly, I thought of your x'(n), and how you mentioned trigonometric _interpolation_; so, to make things valid, it must be stated that x(n) or x'(n) are _interpolations_, _not_ exact, original signals, and that exactness is only at integer `n` from 0 to N - 1. That's completely fine - but otherwise you claim ability to restore an infinite signal from N coefficients, and the day you do that we'll become a Type 3 civilization.

Answer (score 0):

**WINNER**: Olli's solution:

$$
F_{N-1}[k] = X_{N-1}[k]\big(e^{j2\pi k / (N - 1)} - 1\big) + (x[N-1] - x[0])e^{j2\pi k/(N-1)}
$$

**Code + Demo**:

```
def dft(x):
    return np.fft.fft(x[:-1])

def d_idft(coef, x):
    M = len(x) - 1  # N - 1
    exp = np.exp(1j * (2 * np.pi / M) * np.arange(M))
    coef = coef * (exp - 1) + (x[-1] - x[0]) * exp
    return np.fft.ifft(coef)
```

Though, problem not entirely solved. <s>All</s> properties 1 & 2 met, negligible reconstruction loss, and very small difference in coefficients computed directly from `DFT(DIFF(x))` and this method. "Very small" as in `1e-12`, which might be FFT's float error. -- [Comparison code](https://pastebin.com/0Upd0sJ2).

1. Need a relation in terms of $X_N=\text{FFT}(x)$, not $X_{N−1}=\text{FFT}(x[\text{:-1}])$
2. Cannot require the original signal as input to compute $F_{N−1}$ (irrecoverable from $X_{N−1}$).

Since Olli worked out an expression with 1 fewer coefficient ($X_{N−1}$), in a way a harder problem was solved, so a workaround to (1) and (2) seems possible.

---

This answer aims to further refine the problem, test proposed solutions, and explicate flaws in other answers to guide a resolution.

**Slope term**: it's needed, *whether $x$ is periodic or not*. Without it, $Y[0] \neq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (x[n] - x[n-1])$. It somewhat ties to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus; if the finite difference is the derivative, then $x[n]$ is the antiderivative of the function that's the finite difference, so the sum for $Y[0]$ is quite simply $x[N-1]-x[0]$ -- [$\int_a^b f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$].

More precisely, $x[n-1]-x[0]$ equals the *net finite difference* on the interval; try to force this value to be anything else without changing the endpoints - you won't.

---

**Answer properties** - what the resultant expression must satisfy:

1. `len(Y) == N - 1`; the finite difference uses 1 fewer term than `x`
2. $Y[0] = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (x[n] - x[n-1])$
3. $Y$ is expressed in terms of $X$, $j$, $n$, $N$, and maybe its own index - no other parameter; $x$ is fine as long as within $[0, N-1]$, as that's recoverable from $X$.

---

**Properties justification**:

**Olli's answer** suggests a shift with a `N+1`-point DFT&IDFT; *this is invalid*, and so is any attempt at not dropping a sample. It may prove useful in some applications, but is fundamentally flawed and hence not general-purpose. Here's why.

Recall $+C$ when integrating? Same story: *differentiation loses information*. Let $x'[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$. We cannot restore $x[n]$ from $x'[n]$, only its *shape*; the *DC offset* is missing. If we know *any one* original sample, $x[h]$, we can restore the whole signal from $x'[n]$, since we know $x[N-1]-x[0] = \sum x'[n]$, and we'll find $x[n-1]$ via cumulative sum starting at $x[h]$. It's analogous to an Initial Value Problem.

---

**Cedron's result**,

$$ 
Y[k] = X[k]\left( 1 - e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right)  + (x[N-1]-x[-1]),
$$

meets *none* of the properties, but it clearly steps in the right direction.

---

**Cedron's result + mod, tested** (mod = $x[0]$ instead of $x[-1]$):

[image]

The three substantially different magnitude & phase spectra all invert-transform to almost exactly the same signal. Any error seems attributable to float imprecision. Green here is the "ground truth". -- [Code](https://pastebin.com/HBHDPJUi).

What if we modify `d_idft` per above rationale? i.e., drop `coef[0]`, the DC term:

```
def d_idft(coef, x, slope=True):
    M = len(coef) - 1
    coef = coef[1:] * (1 - np.exp(-1j * 2 * np.pi / M * np.arange(M)))
    coef += (x[-1] - x[0])
    return np.fft.ifft(coef)
```

The error grows significant - no good. Also note I pass `x` as input for convenience only.

---

**If what we have already works, why look further?** (i.e. MAE within float64) - because it's simply wrong, and just because I haven't found a signal with significant MAE, doesn't mean it doesn't exist, or that there aren't graver implications in practice.

---

**Test script**: you know your solution works if it passes [this script](https://pastebin.com/5D0XrdUk).

Comment: I'm a little bit disappointed in your implementation of my formula.  Check out the latest followup in my first answer.  ;-)

Comment: [Edited](https://pastebin.com/PUs2uekU) your code a little. So tell me, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyBMt.png) makes sense to you? Because that's the consequence of your trick to get the nice numbers.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Interesting, seem to meet all properties - I'll have a closer look later, thanks for the effort.