# How is wavelet time & frequency resolution computed?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, wavelet, time-frequency, cwt

Mallat gives analytic wavelet time & frequency widths/uncertainties as

$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{ts}^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t - u)^2 |\psi_{u, s}(t)|^2 dt 
               = s^2 \sigma_t^2 \tag{4.51} \\ 
\sigma_{\omega s}^2 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\omega - \frac{\eta}{s} \right)^2 |\hat\psi_{u, s}(\omega)|^2 d\omega 
               = \sigma_\omega^2 / s^2 \tag{4.54}
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
\psi_{u,s}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} \psi^* \left( \frac{t-u}{s}\right),\ \ \hat\psi_{u,s}(\omega) &= \sqrt{s} \hat\psi(s\omega) e^{-i\omega u} \tag{4.53} \\
\eta = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \omega |\hat\psi (\omega)|^2 d\omega \tag{4.52} \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\sigma_t^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^2 |\psi(t)|^2dt,\ \ \sigma_\omega^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty (\omega - \eta)^2 |\hat\psi(\omega)|^2 d\omega
$$

But how would one actually *code* this? Continuous math can't just be ported directly; the following considerations arise:

1. How to treat $\psi(t)$ for wavelets defined in frequency domain? We `ifft`, which now mixes the *discrete* and *discretized*. Any normalization considerations?
2. How to define $t$ and $\omega$, particularly in light of (1)? What are their ranges? For $\omega$ one can presume $0$ to $\pi$ - but what of $t$? Even if we go to infinity, one must still define the interval over which the wavelet decays.
3. [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70837/50076) discusses center frequency computed for wavelets sampled directly in time-domain; is the approach the same here?
4. How to tell whether the implementation(s) is correct? One can always code integrals to spew numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is *units*, and understanding wavelet behavior in context of application (in this case CWT). Full implementations for all discussed here is available at squeezepy.

This answer assumes *analytic* wavelets as per the question ($\hat \psi (\omega \leq 0) = 0$), but all ideas apply to general time-frequency atoms (e.g. windows for STFT) with some code adjustments.

---

#### Time Resolution

Firstly, note we're computing a "width", which is inversely-related to "resolution". The width is the standard deviation of the time-domain wavelet. Standard deviation is well-defined for normally-distributed data, and has desirable properties if data is a [*probability distribution*](https://www.probabilisticworld.com/mean-variance-probability-distributions/).

By squaring modulus of $\psi(t)$ and normalizing it to integrate to 1, we interpret the result as a probability distribution, and define the *time variance*:

$$
\sigma_t^2 = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 |\psi(t)|^2 dt}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(t)|^2 dt},  \tag{1}
$$

where $\psi(t)$ is assumed zero-mean. We thus interpret $\sigma_t$ as as the **time-span of [~68%](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) of wavelet's energy**.

The purpose of the denominator is to enforce validity as probability distribution, i.e. normalizing $\psi$ if we haven't already. This is valuable for coding the integral, as the wavelet at different scales may not integrate to $1$ automatically. It also reminds us of the probabilistic context rooting  $\sigma_t$. Mind that $\sigma_t$ is *half* the said span, as we compute the uni-lateral ('radius') variance.

The question is, how to define $t$? We can't take infinity, and even if we could, what finite width would span the non-decayed wavelet? Answer to latter is rooted in how DFT works, discussed in "Are we right?" below, but there's an extra concern: should `t` be zero-mean? *No*; it should be defined such that it *aligns with the wavelet* as if it were inputs to generate the wavelet.

Most wavelets will peak at $t=0$, for which `t=0` should align with wavelet's peak (i.e. same array index), negative to left, positive to right. Such `t` will be *nearly* zero-mean, but not exactly, and requires different handling for even- and odd-length `t`.

---

#### Frequency resolution

Much of what's said for $\sigma_t$ also holds here; we define the *frequency variance* as

$$
\sigma_\omega^2 = \frac{\int_0^{\infty} (\omega - \tilde\omega_\psi)^2 |\Psi(\omega)|^2 d\omega
                       }
                       {\int_0^{\infty} |\Psi(\omega)|^2 d\omega},  \tag{2}
$$

where $\tilde\omega_\psi$ is the *energy center frequency* (see "Center Frequency"). We thus interpret it as **frequency-span of ~68% of wavelet's spectral energy**. In [CWT filter bank](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwtfilterbank.html) terms, a small $\sigma_\omega$ for a given scale means that most of input signal's frequencies will be band-passed about $\tilde\omega_\psi$, and the rest attenuated/rejected.

---

#### Center Frequency

The cited answer's approach won't work here - at least not directly. Either way it's suboptimal; since discretization favors us in frequency domain, integrating is best. Ref [1] defines three meaningful frequencies one can associate with a wavelet's scales, and corresponding center frequencies; two of those for *center frequency* are the *energy center frequency* and the *peak center frequency*, latter defined as frequency at which $\Psi(\omega)$ peaks, and former as:

$$
\tilde\omega_\psi = \frac{\int_0^{\infty}\omega |\Psi(\omega)|^2 d\omega}
                         {\int_0^{\infty}|\Psi(\omega)|^2d\omega}  \tag{3}
$$

Here we don't assume $\Psi(\omega)$ is zero-mean (in fact it can't be). If $\Psi(\omega)$ is even-symmetric, then energy center frequency == peak center frequency. For finite and coded $\Psi(\omega)$, this distinction becomes significant and crucial to any wavelet regardless of shape ("Edge Cases").

---

#### Are we right?

Three sanity checks:

1. Can results be interpreted meaningfully?
2. Is $\sigma_t \sigma_\omega \approx 0.5$?
3. Does $\sigma_t \sigma_\omega$ scale correctly with varying wavelet parameters ($\mu$, scale, etc)?

#2 is our main check; if the product is much greater or lesser than 0.5, we're off.

To cut it short, I had to 'cheat' to find the proper range for $t$. I started assuming $\omega_\psi$ to be correct since it made sense and correctly gave center frequency as the exact location of the mode=peak. For $\sigma_t$ I ranged $t\in [-.5, .5)$, as that's interpreted as fraction of frame's length. $\sigma_t \sigma_\omega$, however, did *not* multiply to $0.5$.

Working backwards, $\sigma_t = 0.5 / \sigma_\omega$, I found the correct $t$ to range $t \in [-N/2, N/2)$! And then it all clicked: **units**.

The units of $\sigma_\omega$ are *samples per cycle*. Then, to cancel in Heisenberg's relation, $\sigma_t$ must have the reciprocal units: *cycles per sample*. This is unified by below relation for DFT:

$$
\begin{align} f_p \left[ \frac{\text{cycles}}{\text{second}} \right] & = \left( f_{\text{DFT}} \left[ \frac{\text{cycles}}{\text{samples}} \right] \right) \cdot \left( f_s \left[ \frac{\text{samples}}{\text{second}} \right] \right) \end{align}  \tag{4}
$$

which can also be used to obtain resolutions in physical units (Hertz, seconds, etc).

Above is also a bit simplified; the full units are:

$$
\begin{align}
\left[\left[ \sigma_\omega \right]\right] &= \frac{\text{cycles}\cdot \text{radians}}{\text{samples}}  \tag{5a} \\
\left[\left[ \sigma_t \right]\right] &= \frac{\text{samples}}{\text{cycles}\cdot \text{radians}}
\tag{5b} \\
\end{align}
$$

Radians in $(5b)$ are mandated by those in $(5a)$ to cancel in product to yield unitless Heisenberg area. They're also sensibly interpreted once considering the *nondimensional* variants.

---

#### Edge cases

Discretizing problems don't end at finite precision and scaling conversions; consider what happens with `scale` pushed to extremes.

**High `scale`**

Freq-domain not doing too poorly - mainly finite precision imperfections. But *time-domain* is trouble: it doesn't fit the frame! Two problems here:

1. How do we handle $\psi (t)$? Should we *extend* the frame by adding samples until decay?
2. How does our choice in 1 affect CWT?

#2 is key to #1. Recall in CWT with freq-domain wavelets, we do a form of [discretized convolution theorem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70810/50076), getting sort of the *exact* continuous-time result, then discretizing. An imperfect time-domain wavelet is characterized by not fitting in the frame - but what if the *frequency-domain* wavelet fits just fine?

I've yet to meet a time-domain wavelet that doesn't decay sufficiently if the frequency-domain wavelet does; problems arise when the frequency-domain wavelet *doesn't*. At the high scale extreme, the freq-dom wavelet is defined by a *single sample*, which is a time-domain pure sine with $\sigma_t=\infty$. Proper decay demands *even symmetry* of the freq-domain wavelet, which is bare minimally attainable by two adjacent bins at equal values. How exactly various scenarios are handled can be found in `squeezepy`'s `tests/props_test.py`.

**Low `scale`**

Now the time-domain wavelet fares fine, while freq-domain is clearly troubled: half (or more) of it is entirely missing! We have the "trimmed bell" problem, contrary to "insufficiently sampled bell" for high `scale` case. The center frequency distinction becomes critical here; peak will always equal $\pi$, while energy will lie to its left. Investigating the behavior of the $\sigma_\omega$ integral, I found the energy variant to yield stabler and at times more sensible results, but depending on application, peak can also be used (with due re-interpreting of $\sigma_\omega$).

#### Nondimensional measures

Doing everything right above, one can take the Morlet wavelet and vary its `mu` only to notice that time and frequency resolutions don't change! What's the deal?

In short, we need a *nondimensional measure*; this is obtained by normalizing above as follows (thus completing formulae in ref[2]): $\sigma_t \cdot= \omega_\psi,\ \sigma_\omega /= \omega_\psi$ in relevant equations above, where $\omega_\psi$ is *peak* center frequency. As to how this is interpreted or why it works - it's already a lot for one question, so briefly: try making sense of $\sigma_t$ relative to center frequency's time-domain period, and $\sigma_\omega$ relative to spread around center frequency in log space (or simply ratio-wise).

Non-dimensional measures change with wavelet parameters, but not with *scales*, so each has its own use and interpretation.

#### Where's the $2\pi$?

Mallat's equations divide by $2\pi$, we don't, but there's no contradiction: this is per [Parseval-Plancherel's theorem](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejdg/eeft3.pdf) relating time-domain and frequency-domain energies. Since we explicitly divide by said energies in $(1)$ and $(2)$, the $2\pi$ is automatically accounted for.

#### Further reading

Not everything was explained here, nor can be in a single post. `ssqueezepy` contains a [complete implementation](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/wavelets.py), with accompanying [tests](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/tests/props_test.py) that provide further explanation - particularly on handling scale extrema, which is a whole topic of its own.

#### References

1. [Higher-Order Properties of Analytic Wavelets](https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/TSP.2008.2007607) - J. M. Lilly, S. C. Olhede
2. [Wavelet Tour, Ch1-4](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Emallat/papiers/WaveletTourChap1-2-3.pdf) - S. Mallat

Answer (score 1):

We can visualize said resolutions with [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy). Let us compare the Morlet wavelet for `mu=5` vs `mu=20` parameters. For reference, I also recommend [this Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cuypxm8s1y). All plots below (unless otherwise shown) via:

```
wavelet = ssqueezepy.wavelets.Wavelet(('morlet', {'mu': 5}))  
wavelet.viz()  # repeat w/ {'mu': 20}
```

#### Waveforms across scales

[image]

- Heatmaps show top-down view of time- & frequency-domain wavelets across different scales
- `mu=20` is lot more "wiggly" than `mu=5` in time-domain, as expected for higher center frequency
- `mu=20` is much "thinner" than `mu=5` in freq-domain (and wider in time-domain), showing a difference in resolutions (see other answer)
- The two span different range of scales; this is per `ssqueezepy` 'intelligently' picking minimum and maximum, similar to (but not same as) MATLAB's [cwtfreqbounds](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwtfreqbounds.html)

#### Time & frequency joint resolution

[image]
[image]

- Textbook-like plots, showing joint time & frequency widths (widths *drawn to scale*, but not amplitudes)
- Dimensional widths are same for `scale=100`, but not non-dimensional
- Box areas not accurately represented; bounds precision is within 1 pixel

#### Time & frequency widths vs scales

[image]

- Plots compress a lot of information; see respective methods in `ssqueezepy.wavelets` to see how values are computed
- Notice "well-behaved" and "poorly-behaved" ranges of scales; `mu=20` is harder to tame
- Near extrema (low/high scales), distinct discretization problems begin to show (see other answer)
- Heisenberg product less than 0.5 is misleading here; the design decision was such that `std_t` and `std_w` by default more accurately reflect *their own* widths, but not *joint*. Defaults can be changed to ensure area >=0.5 (not recommended)
- Further comments on edge cases in [tests/props_test.py](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/tests/props_test.py)

#### Joint resolution across scales

[image]

- `wavelet.viz('anim:time-frequency', N=2048)` (omitted `mu=5`; see [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/v0.5.0/examples/imgs/anim_tf_morlet5.gif))
- Adaptive resolution nature of the wavelet is clearly seen
- Scale extrema problems are partially observed; can you guess what happens if we push them even further (higher & lower)?

#### How `scales` determine waveforms

[image]

- `wavelet.viz('waveforms', scale=1.5, N=1024)` (repeat for `scale=400`)
- Changing `scales` amounts to changing the spacing of the sampling grid in frequency domain (red dots)
- Partial insight into extreme behavior is obtained by sweeping `scale` near extrema and observing waveform behavior