# What do computed CWT frequencies and color values correspond to?

Tags: wavelet, time-frequency, cwt, ssqueezepy

I wanted to make wavelet transform and represent the frequencies as function of time instead of the scale of the wavelet as function of time. This example that uses `ssqueezepy` does it however I would like to understand precisely first what are the frequencies that it calculates (is it the frequency of the signal?) and then how have they been calculated ?

Moreover, what are the range of colours used ? Is red corresponding to high overlapping and blue no overlapping for instance ?

```py
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy import cwt, Wavelet
from ssqueezepy.experimental import scale_to_freq
from ssqueezepy.visuals import imshow

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200, endpoint=False)
sig = (np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * t) +
       np.real(np.exp(-7*(t-0.4)**2)*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*2*(t-0.4))))

wavelet = Wavelet(('gmw', {'beta': 4}))
Wx, scales = cwt(sig, wavelet, padtype='zero')

freqs = scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, N=len(sig), fs=1/(t[1] - t[0]))
imshow(Wx, abs=1, yticks=freqs,  xticks=t,
       xlabel="time [sec]", ylabel="frequency [Hz]")
```

The time domain is the following:

[image]

The resulting CWT transform is instead:

[image]

Example from the SE post [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85533/why-does-a-signal-with-constant-frequency-have-spots-that-changes-colors-at-a-sp). As observed in the answer to the linked question, the red band is around frequency equal to 7 matching `np.cos(2 * np.pi * 7 * t)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Frequencies

Currently, `scale_to_freq` computes the **peak** center frequencies of wavelets, via `np.argmax(np.abs(wavelet_in_freq))`, which returns the peak's index, and can convert to physical via `* fs`. Relevant reading: [Wavelet "center frequency" explanation? Relation to CWT scales?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76371/50076), and on units, see bottom of [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70837/50076).

#### Colormap

It's [turbo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html), left is minimum right is maximum value. Moreover, by default `ssqueezepy.visuals.imshow` with `abs=1` forces the lower limit to be `0`, which is a good idea for visualizing non-negatives.

[image]

#### Other

> Is red corresponding to high overlapping and blue no overlapping for instance ?

Greater value = stronger correlation (similarity / inner product), of wavelet with input. `out[5, 20] = sum(x * np.roll(psi_5, 20))`, where `psi_5` is in time. See animation under "Continuous Wavelet Transform" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076).

The amount of overlap never affects the values of CWT/STFT, only the total number of values: for frequency overlap, `Sx.shape[0]`, for time overlap, `Sx.shape[1]`. For `ssqueezepy`'s CWT, the time overlap is always maximum, `hop_size=1`, and frequency overlap is controlled by `nv`, CWT's equivalent of STFT's `n_fft` (except `nv` is density, so ~proportional to total number of wavelets).

The time-domain perspective is explained in more detail [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86938/50076) under "Convolution <=> Windowed Fourier equivalence"; it's for STFT, but as far as any individual filter is concerned, they're exactly the same thing.

#### Strength of correlation, in short

First, if unfamiliar with how Fourier transform works, I highly recommend [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY). I've also skimmed [this one on CWT](https://youtu.be/jnxqHcObNK4) - seems visually rich but I've no clue what's in it, maybe a better spending of time.

But in short, in physics the dot product measures the alignment of vectors - the greater the value, the stronger the alignment. It's exactly the same here in time, and similar in frequency: per convolution theorem, "convolution in time <=> multiplication in frequency", and we're multiplying by the wavelets' frequency responses in frequency, for every row of CWT, which measures the alignment of input signal's frequency with the wavelet's - and each wavelet is narrowly confined in frequency. And at the same time, each output point of convolution is the result of a dot product *in time*, and wavelets are also narrowly localized in time - hence, "time-frequency", localized in both!

[image]

CWT output for that wavelet is `ifft` of the plot on right (minus the absolute value which is for visual convenience), which is one row, e.g. `Wx[5]`. For your example that peaks at `f=7`:

[image]

```py
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot
from numpy.fft import ifftshift, ifft

max_row_idx = np.where(np.abs(Wx) == np.abs(Wx).max())[0][0]
max_row_wavelet_fr = wavelet._Psih[max_row_idx]
# unpad by 156 to match `len(sig)`
max_row_wavelet_tm = ifftshift(ifft(max_row_wavelet_fr))[156:-156]

a = max_row_wavelet_tm.real
b = sig
a = a / np.abs(a).max()
b = b / np.abs(b).max()
plot(b, w=1.1, h=.7)
plot(a, title='signal; wavelet of "reddest" CWT row, real part')
```

#### Visualize the filters

You can tell everything about the transform from its filters. Below adds to your code:

```py
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot
from numpy.fft import ifft, ifftshift

# should take `cwt` at least once
psihs = wavelet._Psih
print(psihs.shape)
# show in freq domain
plot(psihs.T, color='tab:blue', show=1, title="CWT filterbank")
plot(psihs[:, :30].T, color='tab:blue', show=1, title="zoomed")
# show one in time domain
# for FFT-convolution, it's centered at index 0, `ifftshift` centers visually
pt = ifftshift(ifft(psihs[-50]))
plot(pt, complex=1, title="time-domain example")
plot(pt, abs=1, color='k', linestyle='--', show=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. However I can not grasp everything: so in simple words when I have red spots it means stronger correlation (similarity / inner product), of wavelet with input from the point of view of frequecy ?

Comment: @User I've added some information.

Comment: Thanks again for the addition  but I am familiar with Fourier Transform. So it is as I thought: red color (in the colormap that you have chosen) means high overlapping between the wavelet and the signal ?

Comment: @User Depends what you have in mind with "overlapping", but it's not the right terminology here. Yes, they "match" more - if you plot the wavelet that generates the "reddest" point, you'll see its "wiggles" exactly match the signal's.

Comment: P.S. I have already watched the video about CWT that you linked and yes it was really helpfull ! Because I knew about Fourier Transform but I am new to CWT.

Comment: Ok... if I have to define "high overlapping" in a more formal way it is the definition that you put in your answer, i.e. " stronger correlation (similarity / inner product), of wavelet with input".

Comment: @User A more complete formulation would be, "a high |CWT| value at frequency `f` and time `t` means stronger correlation (similarity / inner product) of input with wavelet of center frequency `f` time-centered at `t`". Added one last visual.