# Inverse DFT on the first half time domain ("DFT unpad property"?)

Tags: dft, digital-filters, signal-synthesis

Assume to have `c[]` representing N DFT coefficients. The complex-valued signal of N samples in the time domain is computed by `idft(c, N)`.

Is there a straightforward way of reconstructing the signal *just in the first half of the time domain* by manipulating `c[]`, and executing only `idft(., N/2)` multiple times?

Comment: The answer is No, it's not possible. However, if you explain what you're trying to do, and define "manipulate", it may be possible to provide some pointers.

Comment: If the signal in the time domain is all real (or is all imaginary) then you can use just the N/2 coefficients as you suggest. Please clarify is that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirroring isn't required; this simply utilizes ["subsampling in time <=> folding in Fourier"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87121/50076), with duality and an [extra step](https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio/discussions/753#discussioncomment-928936). Hence,

```py
x = np.random.randn(128) + 1j * np.random.randn(128)

xf = fft(x)
A = ifft(xf[::2])
B = ifft(xf[1::2])
rotate = np.exp(1j * 2 * np.pi * np.arange(len(x)//2) / len(x))
x_half = (A + B*rotate) / 2

assert np.allclose(x[:len(x)//2], x_half)
```

Performance-wise, not much gain. In terms of pure FFT, it's more computationally efficient: $2 (N/2) \log(N / 2) < N \log(N)$. However, there's also complex multiplication that's $O(N/2)$. Assuming we pre-compute and reuse `rotate` (sampling `exp(jw)` is expensive), my benchmarks show the naive approach is superior for `N` that's a power of 2, and same or a little slower for other `N`. If we don't pre-compute, naive always wins.

Credit to OP for initial solution.

---

#### Details

`A` folds the second half of `x` onto the first: `xA = x.reshape(2, -1).mean(axis=0)`, or `(x[:8] + x[8:])/2`, while `B*rotate` does the same except the folding is a *subtraction*, `xB = (x[:8] - x[8:])/2`, hence `xA + xB = x_half`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** OverLordGoldDragon gave a solution that is superior to mine on every aspect. He got rid of mirroring, but more importantly he clearly exposed the insight to solve this problem. I hope he gets a shower of points!

It turns out to be not that difficult. At least when N is a power of 2.

The cornerstone of my approach is mirroring.
Vanilla code (python):

```
import numpy as np

def mir(xin):
        n = xin.shape[0]
        return np.array([xin[-i & (n - 1)] for i in range(n)])
```

Now I can build an "unscaled" `dft`, using `mir` and `idft` (which is ifft here):

```
  import numpy.fft as fft

  def dft(xin) : 
     return fft.ifft(mir(xin))
```

I first mirror the frequencies to implement `idft` as radix-2 DIT, allowing in turn to reconstruct only half of the signal.
But I need twiddle factors.

```
def split(xin) : 
    t = np.transpose(xin.reshape(-1, 2))
    return t[0], t[1]

def ifft_half(c):
        e, o = split(mir(c))
        
        G = dft(e)
        H = dft(o)
        
        N = c.shape[0]
        W = [np.exp(-1j * 2 * np.pi * k / N) for k in range(N//2)] #twiddle
        
        return (G + W * H) / 2
```

Comment: Verified; interesting approach.

Comment: Interesting. I must say I didn't understand your original question (I thought you wanted to avoid using half the DFT coefficients). It would be nice to know what is the complexity of your approach compared to a single full-size DFT.

Comment: Good point. This approach requires two $N/2$-point IFFT, one $N/2$-point add and two $N/2$-point multiplication and some memory processes. I think these make the total complexity similar to one single $N$-point FFT.

Comment: Btw, [improved explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87121/50076)

Answer (score 2):

For long sequences, there's very little computational gain from this arrangement.

Consider a sequence x[n] of length N, and its N-point DFT $X[k]$. Denote the first half of $x[n]$ as $x_1$, and its second half as $x_2$, then it can be shown that:

$$ \frac{N}{2}-DFT\{ x_1 + x_2 \} = X[2k] = X_e[k] \tag{1}$$
$$ \frac{N}{2}-DFT\{ W_1 x_1 + W_2 x_2 \} = X[2k+1] = X_o[k] \tag{2}$$

where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the first & second halves of the sequence $W = e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n } ~~,~~ n = 0,1,...,N-1$. Also, $X_e[k]$ and $X_o[k]$ are the even and odd indexed parts of $X[k]$ respectively.

Then, it's a matter of algebra to show the following:

$$ x_1 + x_2 = \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_e[k] \} \tag{3}$$
$$ W_1 x_1 + W_2 x_2 = \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_o[k] \} \tag{4}$$

then, multiply Eq.3 with $W_2$

$$ W_2 x_1 + W_2 x_2 = W_2 \cdot \left( \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_e[k] \} \right) \tag{5} $$
$$ W_1 x_1 + W_2 x_2 = \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_o[k] \} \tag{6}$$

and solve for $x_1$:

$$x_1 = \frac{ W_2 \cdot \left( \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_e[k] \} \right) - \left( \frac{N}{2}-IDFT \{ X_o[k] \} \right) }{ W_2 - W_1 } \tag{7}$$

Eq.7 indicates that the first half of the sequence $x[n]$ is obtained by two $\frac{N}{2}$-point inverse DFTs performed on even & odd indexed parts of $X[k]$ (which is your $c[n]$ sequence).